# WSL2でGPUを使うためにdockerを用いてjupyter notebookを起動したい

Tags: ubuntu, docker, jupyter-notebook, wsl

WSL2でGPUを使うためにdockerを用いてjupyter notebookを起動しようと試みていますが、
表示されたURLをブラウザに入れても接続を拒否されましたと出てしまいます。
以下ページを参考にしています。

[ついにWSL2+docker+GPUを動かせるようになったらしいので試してみる - Qiita](https://qiita.com/yamatia/items/a70cbb7d8f5101dc76e9)

```
$ docker run -it --gpus all -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter

________                               _______________
___  __/__________________________________  ____/__  /________      __
__  /  _  _ \_  __ \_  ___/  __ \_  ___/_  /_   __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
_  /   /  __/  / / /(__  )/ /_/ /  /   _  __/   _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
/_/    \___//_/ /_//____/ \____//_/    /_/      /_/  \____/____/|__/


WARNING: You are running this container as root, which can cause new files in
mounted volumes to be created as the root user on your host machine.

To avoid this, run the container by specifying your user's userid:

$ docker run -u $(id -u):$(id -g) args...

[I 17:56:53.218 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
jupyter_http_over_ws extension initialized. Listening on /http_over_websocket
[I 17:56:53.501 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /tf
[I 17:56:53.502 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:

以下省略 ...
```

実行はできているようなのですが、ブラウザからアクセスができないようです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

**追記**
[WSL2内で立ち上げたサーバにWindows側からlocalhostで接続する - Qiita](https://qiita.com/snaka/items/a8eee4cfc8f7d733e6ab)
を参考にconfigファイルを作ったあと、

http://localhost:8888/
をブラウザに打ち込むとtokenが要求され、表示されたtokenをコピペするとJupyter Notebookに入れました。

ただ、今後のためにも原因を明らかにしたいので、わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご回答をお願いいたします。

Comment: GPU は関係なく、その前段の問題に見えます。一番考えられるのは単に URL を間違っている場合です。ブラウザに「接続を拒否されました」と出るのであれば、token が間違っているのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。`[I 17:56:53.503 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=xxxx`というのをそのまま貼り付けているのでtoken間違いはないと思っています。